# Why electromagnetic radiation happens at high frequencies?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

Why at lower frequencies electric currents do not radiate that much?

Comment: Can you provide some equations which are causing your confusion?  And try to quantify "that much," i.e. show the relationship of power emitted vs.  electric current frequency?

Comment: My question is not based on some equations I worked with. It is based on applications we see every day. For instance tv or radio antennas vs power chords at home at 60 Hz.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Microscopically, this can be traced back to a basic relationship between the power emitted and the square of the acceleration of charged particles - the radiation terms of the electromagnetic fields are proportional to the acceleration and the power is proportional to the square of these fields - see [Larmor's formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larmor_formula).

If a charged particle undergoes a sinusoidal displacement such as
$$ x = a\sin (2\pi f t),$$
where $a$ is an amplitude and $f$ is the frequency, then differentiating twice gives the acceleration
$$\ddot{x} = -4\pi^2 af^2 \sin(2\pi f t).$$
Squaring this and taking its time average gives
$$\langle \ddot{x}^2 \rangle = 8\pi^4 a^2 f^4.$$

There is thus a very strong dependence on the frequency of oscillation and the emitted power.

If expressed in terms of a current, then since current is already proportional to charge multiplied by $\dot{x}$, then
$$\ddot{x} \propto f I$$
and so the power emitted is proportional to $f^2 I^2$.

Comment: Why the emitted power is proportional to the electron acceleration?

Comment: It isn't. It's proportional to the square of the charged particle acceleration. For that you have to prove Larmor's formula @Aria.

Comment: Very minor squabble: $\ddot{x}$ should be negative. +1 from me.

Answer (score -1):

Yes,electric current at lower frequency do not radiate e.m.r that much as compared to higher frequency current. Freq ∝ temp. A rise in temperature of a body increases the intensity (brightness or amount of radiation)of the frequency.
There is a difference between intensity and frequency.I*ntensity means amount of radiation while frequency means the rate of vibration.

You can comment me if you are not satisfied with this answer.

Comment: This is a bit too unfocussed to be a good answer.  You're mixing heating effects (delta resistance with temperature of the wire, perhaps) with the direct radiation caused by accelerating charged particles, which does not require resistance to happen.